# keyboard doesn't work on startup and left ctrl key is seemingly stuck

Tags: keyboard

So a bit of context, I haven't used my laptop for about 4 months because I went overseas. When I got back, my keyboard suddenly doesn't work on start-up (I have bring up the onscreen keyboard first before it works) and the left ctrl key is not working either.

I tried looking up ways to fix the first issue but none of the fixes worked, I also learned that if I press the left ctrl key multiple times it actually works but moments later I suffer the issue of the ctrl key being stuck and it f***s up whatever it is I'm doing.

I must also say that I had my laptop's keyboard replaced last January 2022 but only started to experience the issue when I got back home last March 2023.

I tried looking for solutions online but couldn't find any that woks, maybe someone here can help me?

Comment: Was the computer left connected to the electric mains during these 4 months? If yes, do you any power protection device?

Comment: More likely: was something pressing on the keys wile in storage? If so, most likely the keys are damaged. You can wait to see if the internal spring will pop back into shape, unplug the internal keyboard and use one on USB, or replace it again. For some laptops, a replacement is ~US$10 and takes ~10 minutes... and on others, not so easy.